# Creating an installer for software on Node.js

Tags: node.js

With what can implement an installer for the application on Node.js be implemented with the ability to install applications without access to the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

You may accomplish this by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg to pack your app to a single executable.